# Amazon Linux builds using Packer?

Tags: amazon-linux, packer

I've been trying to chase this down but evidently have not found the right documentation. It it possible (and how) to build Amazon Linux machines with Packer? Would this be just mirror AMI's that are prebuilt if so? I know that Amazon Linux does not have an ISO per-se so this would not work, so I am trying to figure out the methodology around how this is accomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packer takes a source image, and has two builders (instance-store and ebs) for AWS. If you want to pack an application on top of Amazon Linux, you'd just specify one of their AMIs as a source AMI for Packer, then use a provisioner of some sort to set up the app.

Amazon Linux is a proprietary build of Linux; Packer builds on top of an existing OS, so you can build onto Amazon Linux with the Packer AWS builders.

Comment: Strongly recommend amazon-ebs builder. https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html Any AMI input including Amazon Linux AMIs make a suitable input source_ami.